# Нужна ли в тексте запятая после обстоятельственного оборота?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

В связи с «затянувшимся» окончанием ремонта судна «Мыс Тарханкут» нами инициированы и проведены четыре производственных совещания на борту судна с участием представителей.

Comment: Текст переполнен неуклюжими канцеляризмами. Как меожт затянуться окончание? Затянуться может ремонт, но не окончание. Непонятно чьи представители. Почему "затянувшимся" в кавычках?

Answer (score 1):

**В связи с затянувшимся ремонтом судна «Мыс Тарханкут»,  нами инициированы и проведены четыре производственных совещания на борту судна с участием представителей сторон.**

В общем случае запятая факультативна, но здесь обстоятельственный оборот можно обособить, учитывая распространенность основной части сообщения.

Назначение кавычек не очень ясно.

Answer (score -1):

В данном тексте запятая не требуется.